# Android & OpenCV : Utils.bitmapToMat crashes

Tags: android, opencv

I need to convert one of my ressource picture to a Mat from OpenCV, but the app crashes while using this code :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.cmc7);
    Mat myMat = new Mat();
    Utils.bitmapToMat(mBitmap, myMat);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
```

As long as I do not have the bitmapToMat line, everything is fine.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main    
?:??: W/?(?): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat:(III)J
?:??: W/?(?): org.opencv.com.Mat.n_Mat(Native Method)
```

This is quite annoying.

Comment: apparently you are missing some native part.

Comment: Maybe, but how can it be ? This project has the same settings than a sample project that works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oh, you cannot use any opencv - related code, until the manager finished loading  ;)

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}

private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
    @Override
    public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
        if (status == LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS ) {
            // now we can call opencv code !

            Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.cmc7);
            Mat myMat = new Mat();
            Utils.bitmapToMat(mBitmap, myMat);

        } else {
            super.onManagerConnected(status);
        }
    }
};

@Override
public void onResume() {;
    super.onResume();
    OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_5,this, mLoaderCallback);
    // you may be tempted, to do something here, but it's *async*, and may take some time,
    // so any opencv call here will lead to unresolved native errors.
}
```